# Deploy with PowerShell issue

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, deployment

When I deploy my project from visual studio everything is fine, I have a module with some pictures in it and a stylesheet that get replaced on deployment, from the output window:

```
  Retracting solution 'xxx.web.wsp'...
  Deleting solution 'xxx.web.wsp'...
Add Solution:
  Found 3 deployment conflict(s).  Resolving conflicts ...
  Deleted file 'http://server/SiteAssets/Style.css' from server.
  Deleted file 'http://server/SiteAssets/pic1.png' from server.
  Deleted file 'http://server/SiteAssets/pic2.png' from server.
  Adding solution 'xxx.web.wsp'...
  Deploying solution 'xxx.web.wsp'...
Activate Features:
  Activating feature 'Feature1'
```

Feature1 adds the images back.

However, when I deploy with PowerShell the images/stylesheet are not replaced. I am not sure what I am missing as I deactivate the feature, retract/remove the solution, add/install the solution and activate the feature but the stylesheet and images have not been updated.

Some PS (I have multiple site collections):

```
$webs =  get-spsite -webapplication "http://server/" -Limit All
$wsp = "xxx.web.wsp"
$path = "C:\xxx.web.wsp"

$Solution = Get-SPSolution | ? {($_.Name -eq $wsp) -and ($_.Deployed -eq $true)}

$feature1 = Get-SPFeature "d56ba933-9c24-440c-9470-1da208c3085e"

$webs | Get-SPSite -limit all | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Features[$feature1.ID]) {
        Disable-SPFeature $feature1 -Url $_.Url -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
}

Uninstall-SPFeature $feature1 -Confirm:$false

Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity $wsp -AllWebApplications -Confirm:$false

Write "Uninstalling" 

while ($Solution.JobExists)
{
    Start-Sleep 2
    Write "."
}

Write "Removing solution"

Remove-SPSolution -Identity $wsp -Confirm:$false

Write "Adding solution"

Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $path 

Write "Installing solution"

Install-SPSolution -Identity $wsp -GACDeployment -AllWebApplications -Force

while ($Solution.JobExists)
{
    Start-Sleep 2
    Write "."
}

write "Activate features"
  $feature = "d56ba933-9c24-440c-9470-1da208c3085e" 

  Foreach ($oneweb in $webs)
  {
    write-host $oneweb
    $siteFeature = get-spfeature -site $oneweb | Where {$_.id -eq $feature}
    if ($siteFeature -eq $null)
    {
      Enable-SPFeature -Identity $feature -URL $oneweb.URL -Confirm:$False -Force
    }
    else
    {
      Write-Host "Feature $feature is already activated on $oneweb" -foregroundcolor green
    }
  }
```

How come Visual Studio deployment deletes the images but powershell doesn't?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physical files are not usually removed from the Library once a solution gets removed. What you have in Visual Studio is actually specific behaviour to VS replacing on re-deployment, not removing upon deactivation.

You would need to do 2 things:

1. Make sure you add the your module files attributes to
   IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" Type="GhostableInLibrary"
2. Code the Feature Deactivating code to remove files - even better

Comment: Hi Marius, I have actually used the code at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/how-to-update-custom-master-page-and-page-layout-which-is-already-deployed and it works fine when deploying from visual studio but when I use powershell the feature is deactivated/activated but the code in the eventreceiver is not run for some reason. When I use the gui and deactivate the feature manually it also works, but not with powershell.

Comment: Your listing from VS suggest that your event receiver isn't doing it's job when running from VS either are you sure it's working? Try remove -Force from your PowerShell it should only be used if everything is screwed up.

Comment: Ok the issue was that I didn't include Path in the module declaration for the masterpage/page layouts like in the example I posted in my first comment, sorry about that. For VS this didn't matter for some reason.