# When I edit my masterpage in SPD 2010, I get error: Type is not registered as safe

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I am using sharepoint 2010 and have a custom masterpage. In this masterpage I am using a servercontrol. This servercontrol is not an ascx file, but a c# class which inherit from the HTMLAnchor OOTB .NET control. In this class I override the OnPreRender method. In my masterpage I register this class as follow:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="RNWC" Namespace="MyCompany.Portaal.WebControls" Assembly="MyCompany.Portaal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0706e2b063d8c945" %>
```

In my html I am using the following servercontrol:

```
<RNWC:PortalConnectionAnchor runat="server">                                    <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png" runat="server"/>
                                        </RNWC:PortalConnectionAnchor>
```

The problem is now, when I try to edit this masterpage in sharepoint designer and save the change, I got this warning: Saving your changes will customize this page so that it is no longer based on the site definition. Do you want to continue?

When I press on yes and save my changes (for example only a space in the html) and refresh my site I got the following error:

> Type is not registered as safe

When I add this in my web.config file of the web application it is resolved:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="MyCompany.Portaal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0706e2b063d8c945" Namespace="MyCompany.Portaal.WebControls" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

I don't want to add this manually in the config file. What is the best practice to fix this problem?

This is my servercontrol class:

```
namespace MyCompany.Portaal.WebControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the PortalConnectionAnchor class.
    /// </summary>
    public class PortalConnectionAnchor : HtmlAnchor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.Control.PreRender"/> event and registers client script for generating a postback.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            var rootUrl = ConfigListHelper.GetConfigValue("RootUrl");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootUrl))
            {
                HRef = rootUrl;
            }
            else
            {
                HRef = GetPortalConnection();
            }

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your master page from SharePoint Designer then it goes into un-ghosted state and hence SharePoint will use type-safe parsers on all the un-ghosted content.

Make sure that you upgrade/edit your master pages using the Feature activation way. You can check the the following answer with source code is already provided: [How to update custom master page and page layout, which is already deployed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/how-to-update-custom-master-page-and-page-layout-which-is-already-deployed/20176#20176)