# Update Page instance from Page layout SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, page-layout, publishing-page, pages

I have release version(1.0) of Page layout and making page instance around(50-60) Pages from that Page layout.

Now, I have changed some content layers into layout and update it with version(2.0). However,my page instance html coming from oldest one(from version 1.0) and when creating new instance from that page layout, page content came up with latest version(2.0) but it does not effect anything on existing page instance.

Is there any way to forcefully update all pages instance inherited from Page layout?

Comment: How have you deployed/created the page layout? Using Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I deployed it through SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Do you see `meta:webpartpageexpansion=”full” meta:progid=”SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document”` these on your page layout?

Comment: Yes, I can see this tags on `<%@Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>`

Comment: one more thing, I have creating page layout using Design manager(new concept with .html and .aspx) into 2013.

Comment: The problem is when you edit the pagelayout with SharePoint designer it becomes Ghosted. Try to unghost the Page Layout and it should replicate the updates. Have a look at [this thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/how-to-update-custom-master-page-and-page-layout-which-is-already-deployed)